# Why import assignment makes module declaration with a relative module name valid?

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

This particular declaration will compile (and  actually works as expected, that is, providing Prop importable declaration):

```js
import _ = require("./_core");

declare module "./_core" {
  export var Prop: number;
}
```

Without assigned import though one will get `TS2436: Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name.`.

My question is: why this import makes this declaration valid and where in documentation it's covered, since I'm actually failing to find any relevant explanation.

Just to clarify - "./_core" is actually a _core.d.ts file lying alongside with this particular declaration file.

Comment: I assume your declared module's name is `./_core`, not `_core`

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă added a section on what is actually _core - it's not something in node_modules.